# iAds show when using UnityAds

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads

I implemented Unity Ads in my game, I would like to display video ads on game over screen. I use this code to do it:

```
if(Advertisement.isReady())
{
  Advertisement.Show();
}
```

The problem is that when I check my game on iOS for some reason iAds banners display on the top of the page!
I went to monetization settings (advanced) of UnityAds and turned off picture placement. I also disabled "Allow picture ads when no video ads are available (Highly Recommended)" in default video placement options but I still see those iAds banners (saying "You are connected to iAds"). I am not sure if they are debug banners and will disappear in release build.
Any ideas?